# web api in Docker can't connect to SQL Server on host with pre-login handshake error

Tags: sql-server, docker, .net-core

Firstly there are a few similar questions but I have tried all the suggestions I can find and nothing seems to work. If you can find one I haven't mentioned, please comment and I'll try it out.

The synopsis is I'm trying to connect a .NET Core 3.1 web api in a Docker container to SQL Server 2019 on my host, but it fails with `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - Success)`.

I have:

- Docker (desktop) version 20.10.7, build f0df350 using WSL2
- SQL Server Developer 2019 15.0.2080.9
- Windows 10 Home 21H1

I have tried:

#### A different docker image

According to [here](https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/222) people have success with `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-bionic` instead of `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1`

#### port mapping

various forms to `docker run`, including `-p 1433:1433`, `-p 0.0.0.0:1433:1433`, `-p localhost:1433:1433`

#### Connection Strings

My connection string is currently
`"Server=host.docker.internal;Database=xxx;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;UID=sa;PWD='xxx';Integrated Security=false;TrustServerCertificate=true"`

I have also tried `Server=host.docker.internal,1433`, `Server='tcp:host.docker.internal\\SQLSERVER2019,1433'`, `Server='tcp:host.docker.internal,1433'`, `Server='host.docker.internal,1433'`...

#### SQL Server configuration

TCP is enabled and listening on all interfaces, *however* I can't see an IP address in the range 192.168.65.0/24 which is what Docker desktop is configured to use.

SSMS works locally, and the web api app connects if it's not in a Docker container.

#### TLS 1.2

Some comments say it's due to a TLS error with a newer version of SQL Server, however I've tried the workarounds:

1. `TrustServerCertificate=true`
2. changing the minimum protocol on the container:

```
RUN sed -i 's/DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=2/DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1/g' /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf
RUN sed -i 's/MinProtocol = TLSv1.2/MinProtocol = TLSv1/g' /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf
RUN sed -i 's/DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=2/DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1/g' /usr/lib/ssl/openssl.cnf
RUN sed -i 's/MinProtocol = TLSv1.2/MinProtocol = TLSv1/g' /usr/lib/ssl/openssl.cnf
```

### Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-bionic AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:3.1 AS build
WORKDIR /
COPY . .
RUN dotnet build my.csproj -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish my.csproj -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
RUN sed -i 's/DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=2/DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1/g' /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf
RUN sed -i 's/MinProtocol = TLSv1.2/MinProtocol = TLSv1/g' /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf
RUN sed -i 's/DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=2/DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1/g' /usr/lib/ssl/openssl.cnf
RUN sed -i 's/MinProtocol = TLSv1.2/MinProtocol = TLSv1/g' /usr/lib/ssl/openssl.cnf
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "my.dll"]
```

### Full Stack trace

```
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - Success)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenDbConnectionAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenDbConnectionAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.InitializeReaderAsync(DbContext _, Boolean result, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()
ClientConnectionId:88dafbd1-163f-486b-a750-ec3dbf5c75ff
```

Thanks!

[edit]

When I connect to localhost using SSMS, I get a different SQL Server instance. So I tried to connect to the correct named instance from the connection string using `Server=host.docker.internal\SQLSERVER2019;` I get the error:
`System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 25 - Connection string is not valid)`

If I try and use `Server=host.docker.internal\\SQLSERVER2019;` I get
`Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 25 - Connection string is not valid)`

**Note:** I'm setting the connection string as an environment variable to `docker run`: `-e ConnectionStrings__MyConnectionString="..."`

Comment: `network-related or instance-specific error` means server is not reachable. `error occurred during the pre-login handshake` means something is failing in establishing a TLS connection, but the server is reachable. If this is a named instance, are you sure the port is 1433, normally that is only for the default instance. Are you sure your version of `openssl` supports TLS 1.2

Comment: yes regarding the "not reachable" part but that's only after trying some different connection strings so probably a different problem. The pre-login handshake doesn't always refer to TLS, from what I can gather I should get a `(provider: SSL Provider, error: 31 - Encryption(ssl/tls) handshake failed)` if this is the case. How do I configure the port for the non-default instance?

Comment: Remember you shouldn't use aspnet-alpine:X.0 image as the base image in Dockerfile. use aspnet:X.0 instead of that. (Do not use the alpine image. not necessary What your framework is.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*The SQL Server named instance I wanted to connect to was not using port 1433!*

When you use SSMS to connect to `.\namedinstance` it uses the correct (dynamic) port for that instance, so this was throwing me off. Using SSMS to connect to `localhost` gave me an incorrect password error, so I suspected I was connecting to the wrong instance.

I used SQL Server Configuration Manager to adjust the ports for the instance I wanted:

1. navigate to the TCP/IP settings for the instance you *don't* want to connect to
   [image: SQL Server Configuration Manager instances]
2. in my case this instance was bound to 1433. For all `TCP Dynamic Ports` enter "0" and set all `TCP Port` to empty (make sure you do all IPxx items in the list)
   [image: SQL Server Configuration ManagerTCP/IP settings]
3. restart the instance that you just edited
4. repeat steps 2-3 for the named instance that you want to set to 1433, except this time, set all `TCP Dynamic Ports` to 0 and set all `TCP Port` to 1433
5. restart docker

Oddly, after doing this I couldn't use the syntax `-p 127.0.0.1:1433:1433` as I would get an error
`docker: Error response from daemon: Ports are not available: listen tcp 127.0.0.1:1433: bind: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions. time="2021-08-25T10:12:15+09:30" level=error msg="error waiting for container: context canceled"`

However if I used the simpler syntax: `-p 1433:1433` then docker was happy (as was I!)

Answer (score 8):

I ran into this issue today, and I had three instances of SQL Server running on the same machine. 2012, 2014, and 2016. I wanted to connect to 2012, as thats where the database is. I tried setting the port as mentioned in [@thinkOfaNumber's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1089267/thinkofanumber) answer but this did not work for me.

What worked was setting the TLSv1.2 in the docker file;

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:3.1 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
RUN sed -i 's/TLSv1.2/TLSv1.0/g' /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf
```

Comment: SQL 2012 - Worked like a charm.