# Login error from kubernetes pod to SQL Server 2019 Linux

Tags: .net, sql-server, authentication, kubernetes

I've deployed a .NET app as a pod into a Kubernetes cluster but this error occurred when it tries to connect to a SQL Server 2019 :

> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - No such file or directory)
>
> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (2): No such file or directory

This error doesn't occur if I run the app locally or deploy it as a Linux service using the same connection string:

```
Data Source=<ip>;Initial Catalog=<DatabaseName>;User Id=<user>;Password=<pass>
```

Both `Encrypt=False` and `TrustServerCertificate=True` don't work.

Thanks.

Comment: What base (docker) image are you using for the .Net code?  Is your Sql Server running in Kubernetes or running non-K8 somewhere?    Can you drill into your running container and try a "ping" test from it to the Sql Server?

Comment: Hi @granadaCoder. The base image is "mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0",  Sql Server is running on-premise in another server with external access enabled and if I try to ping the IP or the DNS I don't receive any response.  If I try to ping the server from my local PC the response is the same but I can connect to the database using SSMS.
Thanks.

Comment: So if you cannot ping the IP:Port from the container, you'll never be able to have db-traffic on it.  Aka, you need to solve the root issue.  You'll need to figure out your network firewall rules.  Here is a rabbit to chase.. if you're inclined : https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/1402

Comment: As I commented, I cannot ping the server from my local machine but I can connect to it using SSMS. Also, the error says "A connection was successfully established with the server" so it can reach the server but then something goes wrong with "no such file or directory", a very strange error. I've just read the GitHub issue but it is related to a certificate error which is different. However, I tried without any success.

Comment: Rule #1 (IMHO) of docker development.. is that your code running in a docker container is NOT "running from my machine".  Even if the docker-image is running in local docker or something like minikube, it is NOT running "from my machine".  It has to be considered a different machine.

Comment: see below for possible clues : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68915044/web-api-in-docker-cant-connect-to-sql-server-on-host-with-pre-login-handshake-e

Comment: I know you're using "mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0" but is this a legacy .NET Core 2.x app with a dot in its name, e.g.: `Hello.World.dll`? Possibly related, [Publishing standalone app with a dot '.' in name on linux generates executable in an unexpected way #8163](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/8163) by way of [SQLException - error occurred during login #27998](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/27998).

Comment: granadaCoder, I know that but this does not seem a connectivity problem but something related to EF (or maybe the SqlClient used by EF) and docker image.
@AlwaysLearning this is not a legacy app but a .NET 6 app and yes it has a dot in its name but I don't have the problem described in the link. I also tried both DNS and IP/port but the problem is still present.

Comment: "error occurred during the pre-login handshake" *normally* refers to an error with the TLS connection, but I don't think that's what it is here. You can clearly contact the server, there is just something going wrong once you do. Perhaps reinstall it.

Comment: I tried to change the SQL Server instance, even with a windows version, but the result is the same.  So, I think that is something related to Kubernetes or Docker image.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the problem. The real error was actually a connection problem but I've deployed the pod with linked injected and the "No such file or directory" was returned by linkerd (I don't know how or why). Removing the injection, I got the real error. On the server firewall, I opened the 1443 port for the ingress IP which is different from the one presented by the pod to the server. So, I opened a bash inside the pod and with the command `curl ipconfig.me/ip` I got the real IP.
After whitelisting the IP everything works fine even with linkerd.